# can I use visual studio 2012 on multi-monitor config?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to decide which monitors to buy. I will buy 3 monitor anyway but i'm not sure if I should be 23-24 or 27 inches.

The question is - if I can use VS 2012 on 2 or even 3 monitors? How comfortable is it? Can I use "center" monitor for "coding" and left and/or right monitors for everything else? How comfortable such setup is and if it is possible?

Ideally I would like to see "photos" or videos of such a setup.

So far I'm using one 27 inch monitor and I'm pretty happy with it. I'm thinking of switching to 3* 24 or 3 * 27 because there are no space for another programs. But just one 24 inch monitor would be too small for me so I want to "spent" at least 2 24 inch monitors for VS.

Comment: multi-monitor support in apps is generall pretty poor. most apps won't maximize to more than one. some will even crash if you put multiple windows of a single app across different screens.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Yes!** Visual Studio 2012 has *excellent* multi-monitor support. Each monitor can have its own "raft" with multiple tabs, split windows, etc. Just grab a window from the main "island" and drag it onto another monitor to create a new "raft". Everyone on our team has 3 x 19" monitors and can mix and match code, documentation, browsers, etc. on each monitor as needed.

Below is a screenshot I took of this in action:
[image: Visual Studio 2012 - Multi-Monitor Support]
[Full Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lucI0.png)

**For More Information:** [What's New in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063.aspx#BKMK_WindowManagement)

Comment: Let me take some screenshots.

Comment: is it 3 monitors setup? what is preferred 3 * 1920*1080 or 3 * 2560*1440? also you probably can recomment good monitor stand for 3 monitors? also I like your "dark" scheme, where can I download it? I think it would be better for my eyes at night.

Comment: Yes. 3 monitors. My monitors run at 1280x1024, but any resolution will work. Visual Studio will expand to fill whatever space you want. The dark color theme comes with Visual Studio 2012 (it has both a dark and light color theme).

Comment: is it just me or am i crazy? (been a while since I had my multiple monitors, but hopefully soon get them back....Does the taskbar do that by default? if not what did you use to do this?

Comment: By default, the taskbar is only displayed on the "main" monitor (in Windows 7, anyway). I use UltraMon (https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon) to extend it to my other monitors. I have used it for years and it works pretty well.

Comment: +Joseph Sturtevant Looks awesome. Have you had any experience with [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) ?

Comment: Totally off topic, but often I want to see code from different parts of the same file on each monitor, eg, when tracing calls within a class, or see several snippets of code, such as a SQL view, a couple procedures, etc. For this I have a text editor in my second monitor and just copy over scraps (and take notes) as necessary. (I guess you could even have another copy of Vis Studio open.) Realize this isn't what the OP asked but has been handy for me.

Comment: But unfortunately each of this tool windows("raft") are linked with main VS window. If I want to bring another app to front on secondary monitor and I back to main VS window it activates tool window on the secondary monitor. Soit ends up with another app window hidden :| Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, and if you need it, it's worth it. You have a lot of space. Google Pictures -> type in "visual studio dual monitor", there are a few pics. You can arrange the windows in any way :)